# Check if ID is in array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a url passed to my page as such..

```
domain.com/users=1237,3728,5686
```

I have another array whereby in my loop of this array I want to check to see if the ID exists from those passed in the URL.  However I am unsure how to achieve this.  Mostly, it's how to get the URL params into an array so I can make a comparison.

Can anyone help?

```
var user = new Array();
var list_len = realDataUsers.length;
for(var i=0;i<list_len;i++){
    user['id'] = realDataUsers[i].id;
    if($.inArray(user['id'], tousersArray), 1){
        // get selected state for option
    }

    options = options + "<option value='"+"U|"+user['id'] +"'>"+"User ("+user['name']+")</option>";

}
```

Comment: How does the  `tousersArray` look like?

Comment: What's with the `, 1` inside the `if` condition? Please read the documentation before you use an unfamiliar function: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

Comment: You're trap in a similar situation to :  `if (1==1,0) { alert(1)}` because the last argument is 0 so it is falsy. as opposed to `if (1==0,5) { alert(1)}` which is truthy due to 5. Also I would be glad to know the spec term for  this (x,y) thing

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: Does your URL actually look like the example you gave?  Usually there is a question mark like: "domain.com?users=1237"  This post might help: [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)